# Random effects variables in R with both nested and un-nested

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have been working on analyzing some data and had some strange results. I want to verify that I am setting up my model correctly before writing this up. Data below:

```
structure(list(X = 1:6, sub = c("59917f16e339120001fb8c21_fvHlk:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21_uK9Bt:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21_fvHlk:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21_uK9Bt:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21_fvHlk:5fbd11ca7025930168297956", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21_uK9Bt:5fbd11ca7025930168297956"), subject = c("59917f16e339120001fb8c21", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21", 
"59917f16e339120001fb8c21", "59917f16e339120001fb8c21"), age = c(23, 
23, 23, 23, 23, 23), event = c(68L, 56L, 72L, 37L, 71L, 48L), 
    timestamp = c("11/24/20 14:27", "11/24/20 14:11", "11/24/20 14:27", 
    "11/24/20 14:09", "11/24/20 14:27", "11/24/20 14:10"), profile = c("mean", 
    "odd", "mean", "odd", "mean", "odd"), rating = c(4L, 3L, 
    4L, 3L, 4L, 5L), rt_ms = c(2053L, 2370L, 3044L, 1568L, 1112L, 
    1732L), image = c("accordion_1", "accordion_3", "apple_01", 
    "apple_03", "asian_01", "asian_02"), trial = c(7L, 55L, 11L, 
    36L, 10L, 47L), onset_s = c(542.394, 418.52, 570.127, 283.328, 
    563.481, 358.924), profile_rating = c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L), block = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), sub_num = c(179L, 
    154L, 179L, 154L, 179L, 154L), own_pref = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
    4L, 5L), item_num = 1:6, cat1 = c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    cat2 = c(2L, 2L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L), profile_rating_new = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), PE = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), PE_si = c(2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), pro_PE = c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), 
    mean_p = c(3.177631579, 2.868421053, 4.421052632, 4.526315789, 
    4.440789474, 4.0625), med_p = c(3, 3, 4.5, 5, 5, 5), own_pref_nan = c(4L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L), condition = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), group = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), pref_exp = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

So basically, participants in two groups are asked to rate several picture items under different conditions. In this analysis, we are attempting to determine how three continuous regressors predict participants ratings. As of yet, I have a random slope for participant nested in group. I also need a random slope for item (labeled as "image"). Here is how the model is set up at the moment:

```
pref_strat <- lmer(rating ~ age + group * condition * own_pref * profile_rating_new * mean_p * profile + (1|group/sub) + (1|image), data=pref_all)
```

I'm pretty sure my fixed effects are correct but I am less sure about the random effects. Can (or should) image also be nested? Is this even the right set up?

Comment: Yeah, we usually end up breaking this model down anyways depending on which effect explains the most variance. So I also have smaller models such as ``` pref1mean_strat <- lmer(rating ~ age + group * own_pref * profile_rating_new * mean_p + (1|group/sub) + (1|image), data=pref1_mean)```